# jest mocking on relative path

Tags: javascript, testing, ecmascript-6, mocking, jestjs

I'm trying to get jest mocking to work on a relative path. The same code but with mocking `fs` worked great, so I'm not sure why trying to mock my own modules doesn't work

```
// myFile.js
const { cacheFile } = require('./cacheHandler.js')

const myFunc = () => {
  cacheFile(file_name)
}

// myFile.spec.js

const myFile = require('./myFile.js')
const cacheHandler = require('./cacheHandler.js')

jest.mock('./cacheHandler.js')

describe("my failing test :( ", () =>{
  it("should be able to spy on the function", () => {
    cacheHandler.cacheFile = jest.fn()

    myFile.myFunc()

    expect(cacheHandler.cacheFile).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)   
  }
}
```

jest claims that the cacheFile() was never called, eventhough when I debug this I can see that it reached this function...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to mock it like this:

```
jest.mock('./cacheHandler.js', ()=>({cacheFile: jest.fn()}))
```

Comment: Also note you can keep original intact with this syntax
`jest.mock('./cacheHandler.js', ()=>{
const original = jest.requireActual('./cacheHandler.js')
return {
… original,
cacheFile: jest.fn()
}
})`